# Convert a project from OutSystems to C# Visual Studio solution

Tags: c#, outsystems

We have an OutSystems subscription and we like to convert/ export that code into C#. Is there a "reverse-converter" or any other export tool?

I am unable to define the approach and any help in this direction will be most useful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. the steps are as follows:

1. You must first cancel your contract with OutSystems
2. Once you have done this, then, and **only** then, they will supply you with C#/ASPX code for your solution.

They won't do this until you cancel the contract.

Comment: Cool, but when they do supply the code, will that be a 100% complete and work straight in visual studio?

Comment: HAHAHAHAHAHA. 
If they were going to do that they would supply the code every time you did a build. They supply the code only when it is too late to complain.

Comment: so what do they supply then?

Comment: I don't know, I only know they won't supply it until you cancel your contract. Then they PINKY PROMISE you get a perfectly good set of code. … but no way to check beforehand if it actually compiles.

Comment: Happy to help!!

Comment: Exporting the source code is also available during product evaluation, so you can use that period to evaluate the quality of the exported code.

Comment: @Ben what's the point of getting it on-demand? You can't do any changes and "import it back" into the product. Whoever uses OutSystems, is not looking to use OutSystems as an easier way to build ASPX code - it's looking for an easier way to build applications as a whole. So, if the money you spend on licensing is not worth the time you're saving on current developments (corrective maintenance of a "very, very stable app"), you cancel the license and get your code because you're not taking advantage of it anymore. They sell a platform, not a product to build ASPX pages.

Comment: @ArmandoGomes the point is **I don't trust them**. Getting it on demand is the only way to make sure you can create a migration path away from Outsystems, and therefore the only way to make sure your business does not become a prisoner of Outsystems. The fact that they don't give it on demand tells me their **intention** is that I **should** become a prisoner locked into their expensive solution.

Comment: @Ben if you don't trust a company neither the signed contracts between parties, then you should look for another vendor. Obviously, their interest is that you remain as their customer - any business loves to keep customers. I'm an OutSystems MVP, just for disclosure. Creating a migration path from OutSystems shall involve OutSystems itself, because it means that you want to stop being their customer. If you want, I can (try to) get you numbers on % of customers that requested the source code and any more related info. Just let me know.

Comment: @ArmandoGomes I asked for the generated source and the company flatly refused. This is not the action of a trustworthy supplier in my opinion.

Comment: @Ben were you in an eligible position to request the source code? I.e., ending your contract or during product evaluation? Because if you were and you didn't get it, then we have a problem that I would like to follow up. If you were not, well... that's a different story - with the refusal being a sign why they are thrustworthy: there's a contract to be followed upon.

Comment: @ArmandoGomes putting such a restriction in the contract is, in my opinion, a trap, and a clear indication of bad faith in itself. I have explained why. You may disagree with my opinion, that is up to you.

Comment: @Ben I agree that we won't agree. I'll ask you that, in the case that you didn't had a pleasant experience, that you approach the company and tell them that. Other than that, I would ask to not make assumptions on the good faith - and signed contracts - of a company, possibly misleading other (current/prospective) users of the platform.

Comment: @ArmandoGomes If Outsystems policy has changed and they no longer put this in their contracts and now give source code on request, then I would be glad to know that. Otherwise, I am setting out what happened for me. If others think "that's fine why is he making a fuss" then that's their business. I do not think it is fine, and I am warning others of this behaviour, which I personally consider bad.